# Cannot debug gatsby website in chrome dev tools

Tags: gatsby

When I run `gatsby develop` and try to add a breakpoint in chrome dev tools, the break can only be added at the beginning of the line, but I cannot add a breakpoint anywhere else.

I havent added anything else to my gatsby config other than the plugins that I use.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add configuration for Webpack to output source maps.

In `gatsby-node.js`, add the following:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        devtool: "eval-source-map"
    });
};
```

Source: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6877